# Form within a non-white background strange borderrs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Within a div with a non-white background, when I add an input element it gives me this ugly border.

[image]

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="search" style="height:30px;">
</div>
```

What can I do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is unusual... what browser are you using to view this? Do you have a source page you can show us? I'm wondering whether it's a browser-defined default, or you have some other CSS causing this.

Regardless, there is a simple answer to this: Set your own border.

Like so:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="search" style="height:30px; border: 1px inset grey;">
</div>
```

You can also use this instead if you want iPhones to render the exact same border too (Apple devices like to style things their own way and this will override that):

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="search" style="height:30px; border: 1px inset grey; -webkit-appearance: none;">
</div>
```

I would still recommend posting a link to a real example (perhaps on jsfiddle.net), just so we can verify what's causing the border issue. There are several possible reasons, though the above code should solve the most common ones.

Comment: I am using Firefox version 32 on Ubuntu. But this solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.